# WooCommerce email post author confirmation not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the WooCommerce Bookable Product extension and have set it so that the booking is emailed to the admin for confirmation - I am trying to hook into this using the new booking class file so that it emails the author of the post rather than the admin - this doesn't seem to be working however.

Here is my code:

```
$productTitle = $this->object->get_product()->get_title();

        $theProdID = get_page_by_title( $productTitle, 'object', 'product' );

        $post = get_post( $post = $theProdID, $output = OBJECT, $filter = 'raw' );

        $author_id = $post->post_author;

        $emailToSend = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $author_id );

            $this->send( $emailToSend, $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );
```

I have put the full class file here http://pastebin.com/Zk6BLVGS

Comment: Have you tested that $author_id and $emailToSend both have expected values?

Comment: @Kkinsey I havent, could you advise the best way to test these?

Comment: Echo the values to the screen if apropos, or write them to a file you can read after running the script, or mail them to yourself, although, since we're debugging a call to mail() that probably wouldn't be the best strategy.

$author_id = $post->post_author;
file_put_contents("/tmp/mydebug.txt","The author ID: $author_id",FILE_APPEND);